# Why is my mac's host file missing the fe80::1%lo0 localhost entry?

Tags: macos, hosts-file

I searched all over the internet but cannot find any answers that make any sense to me.  Can anyone please explain for less experienced users like me, why my mac's host file might be missing the fe80::1%lo0 localhost entry?--in simple terms?

Mine has all the typical clean entries for mac OSX systems there, except it's missing that last line. Is this something to concern myself with? Should i try to change the hosts file to the typically expected one by manually adding this fe80::1%lo0 localhost line, or just leave it as is? Would it break anything to leave it as is, and if so, what?

I am using iMac desktop, version El Capitan 10.11.6.

Here is copy of how my own hosts file reads:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
#
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be there? Is anything not working for you? (I have no such entry either in my hosts file.)

Comment: Is that entry normally present on macOS? I don't think I've ever seen it on any Linux nor BSD, and frankly it seems completely useless. (And calling it `localhost` is outright *wrong*.)

Answer (score 0):

That entry which you claim is missing is not a standard line of the macOS /etc/hosts file. It should not be expected to be present.

Comment: Hi and thanks guys! The reason i had thought it should be there, @slhck, is from a few help sites i found online, including: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7442746 : posted jan 9 2016
 “A clean hosts file looks like this:

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
#

Comment: however, i am relieved to hear that that last line (which did include the "local host" bit, as you can see from my pasted text above, which i copied from that official apple help site!) need not be present, and may in fact be useless. :)